# Append individual words to a set such that I get unique letters

Tags: python

I want to be able to append words to a set such that the unique values are considered within each word and not for the entire string of words.

So something like the following is giving me all unique letters, but instead, what I want returned all words, only with their unique letters: so for instance, below, it would return all words, except "mom" would be "mo" since m is a duplicate.

Thanks much

```
def splt(t):
    newset = set()
    
    t.split()
    for word in t:
        newset.update(word)
    
    return(newset)

t = 'say hi to your mom'
splt(t)
```

Comment: It seems you want one set per word, not one set for the whole string? What is the expected result in this example?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point...how would I get individual sets then?

Comment: Create them inside a loop, not outside.

Comment: Ah, I'll try that now! Thanks!

Comment: Am-a-zing. Thanks so much! That's a good thing to know in general.

Comment: How would I put these sets back into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings can be iterated through just like lists so no need for split. As well you can use the "in" operator to check if a value is already in a list. I think this code works the way you want:

```
test = "this is a test"
chars = []

for each in test:
    if each not in chars:
        chars.append(each)

print(chars)
## output: ['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', 'e']
```

Please let me know if you have any questions or problems!

Edit:

Per the OP I re-wrote the code for the intended output

**Example:**

```
test = "this is a test"
words = []


for each in test.split():
    new_string = []
    for char in each:
        if char not in new_string:
            new_string.append(char)
    words.append("".join(new_string))

print(" ".join(words))
## output: this is a tes
```

I just use `" ".join(words)` to show the output as a string with spaces. The words list will be in the order that you pass the sentence in.

Again let me know if you have and problems or further questions!

**Edit Edit:**

Op was having trouble encapsulating into a function:

```
test = "this is a test"  

def rep_letters(s):
    words = []
    for each in s.split():
        new_string = []         
        for char in each:             
            if char not in new_string:                 
                new_string.append(char)         
        words.append("".join(new_string))
    return(" ".join(words))

print(rep_letters(test))
```

Comment: Yes, I actually am familiar with this; then I would just convert it back to a string with str(chars)...The final function would just have to output a string.

Comment: @James So is the actual output you want "This is a tes". Sorry, having trouble understanding exactly what you want the output to be.

Comment: @James My edit should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Quick question: When I put it into a function, I seem to only get 'tes' but not 'this is a'. 
```test = "this is a test"

def rep_letters(s):
    words = []
    for each in s.split():
        new_string = []
        for char in each:
            if char not in new_string:
                new_string.append(char)
        words.append("".join(new_string))
    return(" ".join(new_string))

rep_letters(test)```

Comment: @James It is because your using `return(" ".join(new_string))` which would only be the last word. All the words are in the words list so you would need to do `return(" ".join(words))` EDIT: Check the second edit on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension with condition. To remove words that have repeated characters just check for the length of unique characters to the length of the word itself.

```
[word if len(set(word)) == len(word) else ''.join(set(word)) for word in t.split()]
```

Output

```
['say', 'hi', 'to', 'your', 'mo']
```